# Publish to web(public) not visible and can't download created report in power BI server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have created a report in my power bi using create report, but I am not able to download the created report, it is saying "You can't download this report. Refer to power BI documentation for the list of download limitations and known issues"I am using premier account in power BI.And also I am not able to view the Publish to web(public) in the report I have created from the power BI desktop and published to the workspace. I have enabled the publish to web(public) in the admin portal for existing embed codes and also enabled to allow new users to create embed codes.

Even after doing this I am not able to see the download option or publish to web(public). And also I am not able to view or get the public link from the embed codes in the workspace settings.

Image for the downloading issue
[image: Image for the downloading issue]

Here I needed publish to web(public) option but not visible
[image: Here I needed publish to web(public) option but not visible]

Created a new report from the semantic model, yet not able to download the created file from semantic model.

I also deleted my reports and re-published again, and yet could not find the publish to web(public) or download option in my power BI workspace.

I even tried to download the latest version and tried to publish to web(public) yet not able to find the option.

Comment: Are you sure this question is programming-related? [ask]

Comment: is your dataset in the same workspace as your report?

Answer (score 0):

Is your dataset is in a different workspace, publish to web is not supported. There are a number of other criteria as well. Please see Microsoft documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. But I had different issue and was able to fix it.
Here is how I fixed.

1. Sign in to azure.portal.com website, and navigate to app.
2. Select "Microsoft Entra ID" or App registrations
3. Follow this link to add a new registrations in azure. "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http"
   "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-tenant"

After following these steps I had to create a new dataset for the Publish to web(public) option to visible.
So I created a new dataset through postman and created semantic model for the recently created dataset and published the new report into power BI service.